# SqlAlchemy table name reflection using an efficient method

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using the code below to extract table names on a database at a GET call in a Flask app.:

```
session = db.session()
qry = session.query(models.BaseTableModel) 
results = session.execute(qry)
table_names = []
for row in results:
    for column, value in row.items():
        #this seems like a bit of a hack
        if column == "tables_table_name":
            table_names.append(value)
print('{0}: '.format(table_names))
```

Given that tables in the database may added/deleted regularly, is the code above an efficient and reliable way to get the names of tables in a database?

Comment: Use `row["tables_table_name"]` instead of second loop?

Comment: Generally when trying to optimize something you should follow this flow: 1. measure performance, 2. if not satisfied with performance go to (3) else exit. 3. find and apply optimizations and go to (1). Doing (3) without doing (1) and (2) is bad, since you will very likely end up with antipattern called premature optimization.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin  Thanks, that will save a few lines of code and probably a bit of execution time. I was wondering if the sqlalchemy methodology used is best practice for my goal?

Comment: `BaseTableModel` is not a SQLAlchemy thing, right? It's just a table you created? If so, doing plain select is probably the fastest approach you can get.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin BaseTableModel inherits from the Model object Flask Appbuilder which in turn inherits from SqlAlchemy but I am not clear on exactly what is going on with FAB behind the scenes.

Comment: I don't have experience with Flask AppBuilder, so can help with this. If it's table containing all other table names, than you have fastest approach.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin if you could put this in an answer Im happy to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious optimization is to use `row["tables_table_name"]` instead of second loop.

Assuming that `BaseTableModel` is a table, which contains names of all other tables, than you're using the fastest approach to get this data.